# Android - hidden text --> show text for 2 seconds --> hide text again

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep

I am developing a board game that user plays with android. Since android is quite fast, I want to fake that android is performing some tough calculations and thus needs time for its next move.

What I want to do:-

1. User turn - he moves.
2. Android turn - android shows text "I am thinking" for 2 seconds
3. Android hides that text and **and only after that** moves his turn.

I tried doing:-

```
onAndroidTurn(){
    textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But what happens is that thread sleeps but text is not shown (okay I know why).

Then searching on stackoverflow, I learnt a way:-

```
onAndroidTurn(){
    textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            void run() {
                textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Now what this does is that it runs that text in another thread and android's turn is updated on screen and after moving it's turn android showing "Thinking" is total stupidity.

What can I do for this?

Comment: instead of a text view have you tried showing a toast message and then sleeping?

Comment: that's because you end the android's turn after returning from onAndroidTurn, which happens instantly.

Comment: @chancea : No, but toasts are not that attractive. Still thanks for your time :)

Comment: @njzk2 : So what should I do then?

Comment: there is too few code to know how your game works, but basically, the action of hiding the text should be associated with the action of moving. i.e. both should be performed in the same function, said function should be called after the 2 sec delay.

Comment: I tried that, but what happens is that since android's turn code runs in a parallel thread, user has a option to move his turn and that may lead to incorrect operation! i.e. user won't know what android moved and he moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- Show "I'm thinking"
- Calculate your move but don't actually do the move, just store it for a while
- Schedule timer
- When timer runs out remove the text and do the move

Something like this:

```
onAndroidTurn(){
    textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    saveMove(calculateNextMove());
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        void run() {
            textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            doNextMove(restoreMove());
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just use an AsyncTask (like this pseudo-code):

```
private class ShowTextTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     protected void onPreExecute(Void... result) {
         textView.setText("Initital");
     }     

     protected Long doInBackground(Void... urls) {
         Thread.sleep(2000);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void... result) {
         textView.setText("After 2 seconds");;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i did it like this:-

```
public void androidThinking(){
    textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    androidThinking = true;    //explained below
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            droidThink.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //CODE  for android's turn
            androidThinking = false;  //explained below
        }
    }, 2000);
```

androidThinking when set to true prevents the user from moving his turn by forcing the listener for user's button to return prematurely

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if(androidThinking)
      return;
```

Thanx everyone for your reply.